# Select all affected rows by rowspaned cell on datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, html-table, multi-select

I have the below

[image]

What I want is, when i select the BOX00099 cell, the three rows right to be selected. 
Also, when i select one of those three rows, the other two rows and the BOX00099 to be selected.
So, the idea is to consider all the three rows as a single row.

Comment: Show the actual code.

Comment: It is a Windows Form Application, it's not important how I populate the datagridview, the trick it's only in on SelectionChange event.

Comment: [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Since seeing the code is “not important”… then I can only assume seeing an answer is equally “not important?”

Comment: Well ok. The datagridview it's a custom control class which I get it [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34037/DataGridVewTextBoxCell-with-Span-Behaviour). Then I just declare the columns, fill the datagridview, and create the spans with `cell.RowSpan = nr` 

I fill datagridview with following code

`dataGridView1.DataSource = Boxing_History.getHistoryBoxing(getStartingDatetime(), getEndingDatetime(), txtBoxNo.Text, out getDataStatus);`

Comment: After looking at the link in your last comment, how are you going to determine if a “selected” row is actually “part” of a merged group of rows? Example, using the picture above, if the user selected the row shown… then, when the selection changed event fires and we get the row number of that selected row… how would you know that “THAT” row is actually merged with other rows in column one (1)?

Comment: I solved, thank's everyone. 
@JohnG, I order them by the BoxNo column value, and then I merge every neighbor cell row with the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem and for those who may have the same problem as me, that's how I did it:

I used an extended datagridview instead the normal one.

```
public partial class DataGridViewEx : DataGridView
{
    public DataGridViewEx()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }

    protected override void SetSelectedRowCore(int rowIndex, bool selected)
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        base.SetSelectedRowCore(rowIndex, selected);
        int index = rowIndex;
        while (index < this.Rows.Count - 1 && this.Rows[index].Cells["BoxNo"].Value.ToString() == this.Rows[index + 1].Cells["BoxNo"].Value.ToString())
        {
            base.SetSelectedRowCore(index + 1, selected);
            index = index + 1;
        }
        index = rowIndex;
        while (index > 0 && this.Rows[index].Cells["BoxNo"].Value.ToString() == this.Rows[index - 1].Cells["BoxNo"].Value.ToString())
        {
            base.SetSelectedRowCore(index - 1, selected);
            index = index - 1;
        }
        this.ResumeLayout();
    }
}
```

Then I add the columns from [this project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34037/DataGridVewTextBoxCell-with-Span-Behaviour). The project has a demo, so you have an example how to use it. To span a cell, I use

```
var cell = (DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx)dataGridView1[0, index];
            int nr = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Nr"].Value;
            cell.RowSpan = nr;
```

After that, to go from the "3 spaned row" to another row with the key up/down, I has to press the up/down botton 3 times (selecting every row one by one from the "3 spaned row". To solve this, I use it the key press event as above:

```
 private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int current = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Down)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                dataGridView1.SuspendLayout();
                for (int i = current; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["BoxNo"].Value.ToString() != dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["BoxNo"].Value.ToString())
                    {
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["BoxNo"];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                dataGridView1.ResumeLayout();
            }
            else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                dataGridView1.SuspendLayout();
                for (int i = current; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["BoxNo"].Value.ToString() != dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["BoxNo"].Value.ToString())
                    {
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["BoxNo"];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                dataGridView1.ResumeLayout();
            }
        }
    }
```